# Mixed effects model with different number of timepoints in each group

Tags: mixed-model, anova

I have 2 groups, patient and controls, and I want to look at group differences in brain activity. My patient group also got an intervention but the controls did not. I’m predicting that there will be a difference in brain activity in the baseline but we won’t find a group difference with the intervention. I want to run this in mixed effects ANOVA rather than doing separate t-tests but I’m not sure what to do about having two timepoints in one group but not the other. Any advice? Should I just do t-tests?

Answer (score 0):

Mixed effects model should be OK even though one group only has baseline measurement. I would use two fixed effects: patient group indicator variable (1 or 0) and patient by treatment interaction. One random effect for subject.
How do the results compare with the two t-tests?